# How can I ignore excluded images in this query?

Tags: php, magento

I have this query, it is not written by me and I'm not very good at PHP and Magento. I have this client who has several images in some products, lets say, there are 14 images for one product but half of them are excluded and they don't want to show them. So my query returns all pictures for each product. You can see the code below:

```
    $_mediaGalleryData = $_read->fetchAll('SELECT
            main.entity_id, `main`.`value_id`, `main`.`value` AS `file`,
            `value`.`label`, `value`.`position`, `value`.`disabled`, `default_value`.`label` AS `label_default`,
            `default_value`.`position` AS `position_default`,
            `default_value`.`disabled` AS `disabled_default`
        FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `main`
            LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `value`
                ON main.value_id=value.value_id AND value.store_id=' . $store_id . '
            LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `default_value`
                ON main.value_id=default_value.value_id AND default_value.store_id=0
        WHERE (
            AND main.attribute_id = ' . $_read->quote($_mediaGalleryAttributeId) . ')
            AND (main.entity_id IN (' . $_read->quote($collection->getAllIds()) . '))
        ORDER BY IF(value.position IS NULL, default_value.position, value.position) ASC
    ');
```

I have added value.disabled=0 like this:

```
        WHERE (
            value.disabled = 0
            AND main.attribute_id = ' . $_read->quote($_mediaGalleryAttributeId) . ')
            AND (main.entity_id IN (' . $_read->quote($collection->getAllIds()) . '))
```

But it did not work either. Any ideas on how can I work that out?

EDIT: So I changed my code to following but still getting the same result;

```
$_mediaGalleryData = $_read->fetchAll('SELECT
            main.entity_id, `main`.`value_id`, `main`.`value` AS `file`,
            `value`.`label`, `value`.`position`, `value`.`disabled`, `value`.`label` AS `label_default`,
            `value`.`position` AS `position_default`,
            `value`.`disabled` AS `disabled_default`
        FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `main`
            INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `value`
                ON main.value_id=value.value_id AND value.store_id=' . $store_id . '
        WHERE (
            value.disabled = 0
            AND main.attribute_id = ' . $_read->quote($_mediaGalleryAttributeId) . ')
            AND (main.entity_id IN (' . $_read->quote($collection->getAllIds()) . '))
        ORDER BY IF(value.position IS NULL, value.position, value.position) ASC
    ');
```

Comment: You are using two left join that they are the same. Delete the second left join because is the same than the first. And delete too the names of default_value in the select.

Comment: @sandrita I actually saw that as well, I just did not want to touch to code as I don't have much idea how would it affect other stuff. Do you think making this change would fix my problem too?

Comment: You can test deleting this. If does not work, put it again.

Comment: @sandrita I edited my code but I'm still getting the same result. You can see edited version above.